# OpenGL: Adjusting LOD angle?

Tags: c++, opengl

There must be some setting to adjust the angle when my textures miplevel changes... isnt there?

It looks really ugly when the miplevel changes really early when my camera is looking at the road with angle of 10 or etc, or angle of 0 but looking straight forward to the road.

What is the magical line of code?

AND NO. not the LOD BIAS thing, ive got that already... its not the way to fix this.

Comment: You need to enable anisotropic filtering for triangles you're looking at nearly sideways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "mipmap changes".  The mipmap level (and anisotropy, if enabled) will be selected per-texel during rendering.  The typical trilinear filtering will blend between them.

You're probably complaining about texture anisotropy.  When viewing a surface edge-on, simple mipmapping can't get you a texture that simultaneously preserves detail (avoids "fuzzies") and prevents aliasing.  This is because the pixel pitch along one direction is much higher than along the other.  Take a look at the GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY texenv setting (originally part of an extension, now in core, I think?) for details.

Comment: i cannot find such thing as "GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY" in my libraries, "symbol is not defined" error comes... what i do?

Comment: It's an extentsion.  Here's a sane-looking tutorial (though I didn't read the whole thing) that covers it:  http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=Programming/Code%20Snippets/OpenGL/anisotropicfiltering  But broadly, reading up on "anisotropic texture filtering" in general would help you to understand the problem.